# Why isn't this simple batch script working?

Tags: batch-file

```
>@echo off
>cd C\users\admin
>mkdir "1"
>cd C\users\admin\1
>mkdir "2"
>move "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\*" C:\Users\admin\1\2
```

cant figure out why this isn't working it just makes the "1" and "2" files in the same place my bat file is and moves nothing, the last line work on its own if i make the 1 and 2 directories for it.

Comment: C: not C should fix it cd C\users\admin should be cd C:\users\admin and cd C\users\admin\1 should be cd C:\users\admin\1

Comment: You should be able to do that those six commands in two, 1. `@MD "C:\Users\admin\1\2"` 2. `@Move /Y "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\*" "C:\Users\admin\1\2"`. Although a one liner may be more fun, `@RoboCopy "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop" "C:\Users\admin\1\2" /Mov`. You may wish to incorporate one or more other options into this, so take a look at the usage information for the RoboCopy command, by entering `robocopy /?` at the Command Prompt.

Comment: Please take note that as your command is most likely, moving between two different profiles, you may need to run the script with sufficient privileges for both accounts.